# Building a train movement graph

Tags: javascript, graph, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

I need to build a graph that reflects train movement for a daily period. Something like this:

[image]

I've never built graphs like that. Have you any idea what I should start with? I found a graphic library `d3.js` but yet have no experience of working with it.

Can you guide me a little?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like E.J. Marey's 1880's train schedule, which is on the cover of [Tufte's "The Visual Display of Quantitative Information"](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_vdqi) and described in [this blog post](http://marlenacompton.com/?p=103).

There's actually an [interactive visualization of CalTrain schedules](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/caltrain.html) that copies Marey's visualization, built in Protovis. Though Protovis isn't actively developed any more, you may just be able to use that example.

However, as @HBP says, this kind of visualization would be pretty straightforward to build by hand without learning any specialized visualization library.

Answer (score 2):

Your first task would be to organize and understand your data. From what I can see in your (smallish) image, you have a grid overlaid with a diagonal lines. Assuming you go with a graphic library I would first draw the grid, adding the grid intersection co-ordinates to the data structure. Then it should be a relatively simple matter of traversing your data and drawing the diagonal lines.

You asked for guidance. Give it a try and if you get stuck come back with the code and data structures you develop.